# Let $G$ be a simple group such that $|G|=p^2q r$ ($p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers) then how prove $|G|=60$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, contest-math

Let $G$ be a simple group such that $|G|=p^2q r$ ($p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers, $r$ some positive integer) then how to prove $G$ and $A_5$ are isomorphic or ($|G|=60$)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $r$ is relatively prime from $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Doesn't this fail for $168=2^2*7*6$? I can only assume $r$ is prime. In that case, the wording of the question implies there are no simple groups when $p > q$ or $p > r$; in fact, when $q < r < p$, the problem can be resolved quite easily using tools introduced earlier in the chapter (that is, assuming this is from D&F, as the wording of the question is identical). The other cases are more complicated but not completely intractable.

Comment: $r$ must be prime, since $360=3^2\cdot5\cdot8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution which makes repeated use of the Burnside Transfer Theorem (or BTT for short), which we can take as:

> **Theorem**: If a Sylow subgroup is central in its normalizer, then the group $G$ is not simple.

Because groups of order $l$ or $l^2$ (here $l$ is a prime) are always abelian, we can use the following form of BTT for this question:

> The normalizer of a Sylow subgroup in $G$ cannot be abelian.

OK, now let's get down to business.

- First, let's count the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.  There cannot be $qr$ of them, since that contradicts BTT.  There also obviously cannot be $1$ of them.  So there are, let's say, $r$ of them. [At this point, $q$ and $r$ are indistinguishable.] Then if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, $N_G(P)$ has index $r$ in $G$. The conjugation action of $G$ on the Sylow $p$-subgroups embeds $G$ into $A_r$, and thus $p^2q$ divides $(r-1)!$. In other words, $r$ is the largest prime dividing $G$.
- Now let's show $p<q$.  If not, then $q$ would be the smallest prime dividing $|G|$.  We would thus have, for a Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$, $|N_G(Q)/C_G(Q)|$ dividing both $q-1$ and $p^2r$; this means $|N_G(Q)/C_G(Q)|=1$, or in other words, $Q$ is central in $N_G(Q)$.  Once again, a contradiction of BTT; so $p<q$.
- Now suppose $Q$ is a Sylow $q$-subgroup in $N_G(P)$.  If $Q$ was normal in $N_G(P)$, we would have $N_G(P)=P\times Q$, an abelian group, contradicting BTT. So instead, there are $p^2$ Sylow $q$-subgroups in $N_G(P)$, and thus $q$ divides $p^2-1$.  Since $p<q$, this means $q=p+1$.  This is only possible if $p=2$, $q=3$.
- Finally, let's count the Sylow $r$-subgroups.  By BTT, there cannot be $p^2q$ of them.  Since $r$ is bigger than $p$ and $q$, there cannot be $p$ or $q$ of them.  Thus, there are $pq$ Sylow $r$-subgroups. This means $r$ divides $pq-1=2\cdot3-1=5$, and so $r=5$.

We have then shown that $|G|=2^2\cdot3\cdot5=60$.

Comment: With BTT we can prove that if a Sylow subgroup corresponding to the smallest prime divisor is cyclic, then it has a normal complement. So that immediately implies that $p$ is the smallest prime divisor and we can assume $p < q < r$. And to prove $G \cong A_5$, we can use BTT again (it implies that $G$ has exactly $5$ Sylow $2$-subgroups).

Comment: @m.k.: the isomorphism with $A_5$ I already covered, I believe, in the first bullet point.  It is the reason I separated the first two bullet points (which, as you mention, can be treated simultaneously).

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that part about $A_r$ in the first bullet point.